# Inheritance of buttons on various scenes from the main GameScene

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

I work with scenes, and all my scenes are inherited from the main scene (GameScene).
And my GameScene is connected to GameViewController through a certain variable (gameViewControllerBridge) like this.

```
  class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
        var gameViewControllerBridge : GameViewController!
    }
```

GameViewController is connected with GameScene thus

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
scene.gameViewControllerBridge = self
}
```

And in my scenes, inherited there is no access to the variable gameViewControllerBridge. And so when switching scenes produces an error, and gets stuck with the line where this variable is, for example:

```
 gameViewControllerBridge.pauseButton.isHidden = false
```

It is necessary that all scenes have access to this variable. So that simulator could call.

Here is the creation of the scene itself

```
 extension GameScene {
 class Scene1: GameScene {
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
 createGame()}
```

The function createGame () I called from GameScene there and the variable gameViewControllerBridge is in createGame()

Here is switching scenes (levels)

```
extension GameScene {

func switchScene () {
switch button.rawValue {
case 0:
let transition: SKTransition = SKTransition.fade (withDuration: 0.5)
let scene: SKScene = Scene1 (size: self.size)
self.view? .presentScene (scene, transition: transition)
case 1:
let transition: SKTransition = SKTransition.fade (withDuration: 0.5)
let scene: SKScene = Scene2 (size: self.size)
self.view? .presentScene (scene, transition: transition)
```

Comment: I do not think you are using extensions correctly,  you do not need to extend when you want to subclass.  Extensions are used to add new methods to existing classes

Comment: I fixed it, but with the buttons that I do.